# UITextField text not aligning properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a UITextField that should be aligned vertically to the center; the placeholder text properly aligns like so:

[image]

However, when text is entered it is aligned at the bottom of the textField:

[image]

In storyboard, I have set it to sit vertically in the center, and furthermore in code:

```
        nameTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = .center
```

I am still baffled as to why it inputs text at the bottom, yet the placeholder sits correctly in the center.

Comment: Try `nameTextField.contentMode = .center`

Comment: @EBDOKUM Excellent! That solved it

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)